# VEEAM RESTORE ERROR : Linux FLR appliance deploy failure : unable to connect by ssh to appliance

Tags: ssh, restore, veeam, appliance

When trying to restore a vm, this error occurs
It may be related to the APPLIANCE VM credentials Im not sure but I don't know how to reset them